# TUS upload video problem in cloudflare stream service

Tags: javascript, php, tus, cloudflarestream

I send request to `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/<accountID>/stream?direct_user=true` with curl in PHP, and get header location value as upload link then pass it to java Script.
this link is like this:
`https://upload.videodelivery.net/tus/xxxxxx?tusv2=true`

and in JS use tus.js for uploading video:

```
var file = document.querySelector('#video').files[0];

var options = {
        uploadUrl: 'https://upload.videodelivery.net/tus/xxxxxx?tusv2=true',
        chunkSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024,
        retryDelays: [0, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000],
        parallelUploads: 1,
        metadata: {
            filename: file.name,
            filetype: file.type,
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer <Token>',
            'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0'
        },
    }
    upload = new tus.Upload(file, options)
    upload.start();
```

but, requests was blocked.
what is solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with the help of cloud-flare team, I found the solution.
There is no need to send `Authorization` and `Tus-Resumable` header on the second request sent via TUS upload.